# Error installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 with vmworkstation 12.0 "kernel panic - not syncing: corrupted stack end detected inside scheduler"

Tags: system-installation, kernel

I am getting an error

```
Kernel Panic - not syncing: corrupted stack end detected inside scheduler
```

This is on vmworkstation12 while installing Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Any pointers on what this could be?

[image: error on screen in VM]

Answer (score 0):

I had encounter the same issue during install `ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` into VMWare Version `12.0.0`. Because Ubuntu 18.04 require version at least `14.0.0` and above.

After I install the VMWare Version `14.0.0` the installation going smooth. Please update your VMware Workstation.

Reference :

- https://blog.csdn.net/private66/article/details/80913379 (Chinese Language)
- https://blog.csdn.net/uvu5629/article/details/80559911 (Chinese Language)