# end kernel panic - not syncing: corrupted stack end detected inside scheduler

Tags: kernel, vmware

I am getting the above-noted error when attempting to install Ubuntu for desktop on a VMware Workstation Pro 11.

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 64 bit for desktop. I allocated 2 GB ram and 25 GB hard disk in memory.  My computer is supposed to be powerful enough (16GB RAM, 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7).

Comment: Can you verify that your computer has CPU virtualization _enabled_? You should go into the BIOS (or UEFI) settings before booting your host's OS and look through the CPU options for it. Start your search for _Intel VT-x_ and/or _Intel VT-d_.

Comment: yes its enabled

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056560/error-installing-ubuntu-server-18-04-with-vmworkstation-12-0-kernel-panic-not)?

Comment: yes but i have VMware 11 pro (not sure i can get an updated pro version), and a friend of mine used same versions (ubuntu and VMware and it works fine so im trying to verify that there is no other option, plus the only refrence there is chinese..

Comment: I know, I'm not too familiar with VMware; VMware Workstation worked on my company's laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad) to talk to other VMs, but I haven't done it the other way around in trying to set it up as OSes on top of a hypervisor running on bare-metal.

Comment: not sure what u mean by hypervisor wunning on bare-metal but thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

The kernel version of Ubuntu OS image that you are trying to install requires a later version of VMWare Workstation in order to run.

There are known (vmware) compatibility issues between versions of workstation and later linux kernals.

For example, I run VMWare Workstation 10.7 and can only install up to Ubuntu 16 by using a patch (which I never have).  I am limited to Ubuntu 14.  Unfortunate, but that seems to be sales model that VMWare have adopted.

It's a compatibility issue.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you may be mixing the issue of building VMware guest tools with a newer kernel with that of simply booting a stock kernel ... so far I only ever had an encounter like this in the combo described by the OP and when trying to run an ancient Redhat (Valhalla) on a modern VMware.

Comment: Oh, That is why I cannot run vagrant box laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 10.1.1) on my oracle VM virtual machinge?

Comment: @0xC0000022L No, I am not confusing the issue.  The stacktrace that the op has added is the same stacktrace you get when you try to run newer versions of Ubuntu on older VMWare Workstation versions.  Its a known issue that VMWare have acknowledged.  The only way around it is to either use a compatible OS version with VMWare Workstation 11, or upgrade to the latest version of VMWare Workstation.

Comment: @stevenbranigan82 fair enough, as I wrote I never had it to that extent with Ubuntu (certainly not a Ubuntu this "modern"), but with Redhat Valhalla.