# Do I need a special .iso for VMWare Workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I keep getting kernel panic error when attempting to create a new VM using the Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS .iso downloaded from https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Nope. There might be some problem in VMWare configuration or ISO. Have you checked that ISO's checksum?

Answer (score 0):

Any installer .iso from any OS should work fine. As a rule of thumb, if you can install an actual OS with it, you can use it to install a VM. That is considered one of the benefits of using virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine found thread relating to the issue:
[end kernel panic - not syncing: corrupted stack end detected inside scheduler](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085943/end-kernel-panic-not-syncing-corrupted-stack-end-detected-inside-scheduler)

Apparently, Ubuntu 16 is the most recent version that can be installed with Workstation 9